# Scrolling in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, objective-c, ios

I want to know if it's possible to scroll to a given id in a UIWebView.

I know that I can scroll to a given (x,y) point using:

```
 [self.myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

I'm loading html files locally so I found that elements in html files can be "labeled" as follows:

```
 <element id="myID">
```

Instead of using a (x,y) coordinate to scroll, I want to scroll to a given id, I tried using this:

```
 NSString *yCoordinate = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('myID').value"];
 [self.myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [yCoordinate intValue]) animated:YES];
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just navigate to the id like this :

```
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"window.location.hash='#myID'"];
```